# Hide an image within an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the following page in an iframe. This page can be accessed outside the iframe as well. But what Id like to do is hide the logo (id=llogo) in the frame but display it when accessing the page inside the frame directly.

```
<div id="content" style="border-radius: 20px;">
<iframe id="contentFrame" frameborder="0" src="/ip/changePassword.html" style="height: 496px;">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html>

        <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Change Password</title>

        <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/common/style.css">   
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/common/jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css">  
        <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/webconsole/login.css">
        <script src="/static/js/common/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="/static/js/common/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="/static/js/common/AM.common.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="/static/js/common/jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="/static/js/common/jquery.boxshadow.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="/static/js/common/change.password.js" type="text/javascript">
        </head>

        <body>

        <div id="pagebg">

        <div id="password">

        <div id="llogo">
            <a class="logo llogo" href="javascript:void(0);">AM</a>
        </div>
        <div id="credentials"> To change your password, enter the information below </div>

        <form id="login-form" method="post" action="changePassword.html">
        <input id="input_logid" class="loginField" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="sysadmin" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" value="sysadmin" name="login" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="currentPassword" class="passwordField" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Current Password" name="currentPassword">
        <input id="newPassword" class="passwordField" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your New Password" name="newPassword">
        <input id="newPasswordConfirm" class="passwordField" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirm New Password" name="newPasswordConfirm">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="postbackURL" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="changeReason" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="managedSysId" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" value="USR_SEC_DOMAIN" name="securityDomain" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="lrow">
        </form>
        <div id="lbuttons"> </div>
        </div>

        <div id="log-foot">

        <div id="copy">

        <div class="dsmweb-footer">
        Login to
        <a target="_blank" href="https://dsm”>DSM</a>
        to access your emails
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        © 2013 AM LLC Copyright 2013. All Rights Reserved.
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 1px;"></div>
        </body>

    </html>

</iframe>
</div>
```

I tried to achieve this by doing,

```
iframe#contentFrame html body div#pagebg div#password div#llogo {
    display: none !important;
}
```

But this didnt do anything. Any ideas how can I hide it ?

Comment: share a fiddle if possible.

Comment: that would be a bit difficult as i have some sensitive stuff there. il see if i can put something quickly.

Comment: `iframe#contentFrame html body …` – that selector won’t match anything. You can not simply select elements that way across documents. Either pass a parameter to the iframe via URL that makes it hide the image itself, or use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you cannot do it with CSS.

But you can try with Javascript. Using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).load(function(){
    jQuery('div#llogo', frames['contentFrame']).hide();
});
```

Remember to set the `name` attribute on the iframe element. In my example, the name must be *contentFrame*, but you can set it as you like.

Beware that the page in the iframe *must* be on the same domain of the parent page, otherwise you can't access the iframe content through javascript, due to the Same Origin Policy. See this other question for more details:
[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)