# Hide image in iframe

Tags: html, css, image, iframe

Id like to hide image in iframe. I am trying this :

```
iframe A IMG {
 display:none;}
```

But it doesnt help, my HTML :

```
 <div class="container-fluid blog-main">



<div class="blog-post">

<h2 class="blog-post-title">

<span><a href="http://martinpodlesak.com/stanislav-dietz/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Stanislav Dietz">
Stanislav Dietz</a></span>
</h2>
<div class="meta-tag">
<div class="cleared"></div>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://martinpodlesak.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=435&amp;action=edit">Edit</a>            
<div>
<p><iframe src="http://www.eliteprospects.com/iframe_player_stats.php?player=72289" width="100%" height="490" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="cleared"></div>


</div>
```

And my website where I am trying to solve the problem:
http://martinpodlesak.com/stanislav-dietz/

Comment: There is an answer to your question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150062/hide-an-image-within-an-iframe

Comment: pretty sure you can't do it because the website inside your iframe isn't accessible by your css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide an image within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150062/hide-an-image-within-an-iframe)

Comment: The solution from the duplicate won’t work here either, because the iframe content is from a different domain, and therefor the Same Origin Policy forbids any access via JavaScript. // What you want is simply impossible using client-side techniques alone.

Comment: I wanted to post an answer to your other question 'choose-of-specific-element-from-xml-via-php', but it got deleted. Are you no longer interested or was it downvoted?